# bluetoothGatt writeCharacteristic returns false

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-ble

I created a peripheral with a WRITE_TYPE_NO_RESPONSE characteristic.
With another application, I wrote on characteristic, but I have an occasional problem with samsung galaxy nexus i9250 with lollipop 5.1.1:
sometimes the function BluetoothGatt.writeCharacteristic returns false and the write is not done.

What could it be ? Can it be cyanogenmod's fault ? And in what way can I patch this problem ?

On peripherall :

```
new BluetoothGattCharacteristic(
                UUID.fromString(characteristic),
                BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PROPERTY_WRITE_NO_RESPONSE ,
                BluetoothGattCharacteristic.PERMISSION_WRITE);
```

**EDIT** : this problems happened only with android >= 5.0.2

Never happened on kitkat and on android 5.0.1 , is a casuality ?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by giving one second gap between to successive BluetoothGatt read/write calls.